# IIFE inside an IIFE. Issues? Performance?

Tags: javascript, iife

My library is an an IIFE like this:

```
(function () {

    win.global = global;

}());
```

inside this library I have my code organized into modules which also look like this:

```
var foo1 = (function () {
    var publik = {},
        private = {};
    return publik;
}());
._extend(global, foo1);
```

where there is a foo for each module.

Are there any issues with having IIFEs inside an IIFE?

Most of the major libraries are encapsulated in an IIFE, but from there they organize their code into simple object literals NOT IIFEs.

That's why I'm asking/curious.

I do this because I like my modules to have private members and this pattern allows this.

Comment: Nope, there should not be any issue.

Comment: Just the usual overhead of a function call. Whether it's an IIFE or a function you defined previously does not make a difference (as long as you only call it once).

Comment: I really think it's a matter of style.

Comment: the reason I find this so perplexing, is that it would seems so easy to get that nice modular ( perhaps even OO ) feel doing this, instead of 10-50 internally dependent functions that are only loosely organized.  Not to harp .... just saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that.

Javascript function expressions can be nested arbitrarily deeply.